# Select random row per distinct field value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query that results in something like this:

```
person | some_info 
==================
   bob | pphsmbf24
   bob | rz72nixdy
   bob | rbqqarywk
  john | kif9adxxn
  john | 77tp431p4
  john | hx4t0e76j
  john | 4yiomqv4i
  alex | n25pz8z83
  alex | orq9w7c24
  alex | beuz1p133
   etc...
```

(This is just a simplified example. In reality there are about 5000 rows in my results).

What I need to do is go through each person in the list (bob, john, alex, etc...) and pull out a row from their set of results. The row I pull out is sort of random but sort of also based on a loose set of conditions. It's not really important to specify the conditions here so I'll just say it's a random row for the example.

Anyways, using PHP, this solution is pretty simple. I make my query and get 5000 rows back and iterate through them pulling out my random row for each person. Easy.

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to get what I would from only a MySQL query so that I don't have to use PHP to iterate through the results and pull out my random rows.

I have a feeling it might involve a BUNCH of subselects, like one for each person, in which case that solution would be more time, resource and bandwidth intensive than my current solution.

Is there a clever query that can accomplish this all in one command?

[Here is an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8679b/2) that you can play with.

Comment: Difficult to tell, without knowing the conditions. Naive answer: if you don't need the data at `some_info`, just `SELECT DISTINCT person WHERE /* you conditions here */`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a random value for a distinct name use

```
SELECT r.name, 
(SELECT r1.some_info FROM test AS r1 WHERE r.name=r1.name ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) AS     'some_info' 
FROM test AS r 
GROUP BY r.name ;
```

Put this query as it stands in your sqlfiddle and it will work

Im using r and r1 as table alias names.  This will also use a subquery to select a random some_info for the name

[SQL Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8679b/43)

Comment: Interesting... is that basically running an extra SELECT query for every single name? Like, in the SQLFiddle, there are 10 distinct names in the table. Is the above query basically executing 1 + 10 = 11 queries all at once?

Comment: Yes... that is a way to look at it. Though this is the way that works.  Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/scalar-subqueries.html

Comment: one more question for you, if I had more columns than just `some_info` that I needed to return in that sub-query, how would I do that? MySQL only seems to allow me to return a single column in the sub-query...

Comment: Yeah I considered the multiple subselect approach. I have quite a few columns I need to return so I think this approach is going to too resource intensive for me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

My first response would be to use php to generate a random number:

$randId = rand($min, $max);

Then run a SQL query that only gets the record where your index equals $randID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
select person, acting from personel where id in (
select lim from 
    (select count(person) c, min(id) i, cast(rand()*(count(person)-1) +min(id)
             as unsigned) lim from personel group by person order by i) t1
)
```

The table used in the example is below:

```
create table personel (
id int(11) not null auto_increment,
person char(16),
acting char(19),
primary key(id)
```

);

```
insert into personel (person,acting) values
('john','abd'),('john','aabd'),('john','adbd'),('john','abfd'),
('alex','ab2d'),('alex','abd3'),('alex','ab4d'),('alex','a6bd'),
('max','ab2d'),('max','abd3'),('max','ab4d'),('max','a6bd'),
('jimmy','ab2d'),('jimmy','abd3'),('jimmy','ab4d'),('jimmy','a6bd');
```

Comment: The solution places no limitation on the number of records per person or total, etc.

Comment: bty: "count(person) c, min(id) i," is not necessary: I forgot to remove it from the final answer. Just order by min(id).

Answer (score -1):

You can limit the number of queries, and order by "rand()" to get your desired result.

Perhaps if you tried something like this:

```
SELECT name, some_info
  FROM test
 WHERE name = 'tara'
 ORDER BY rand()
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That would only return one single result... am I missing something?