# How to select Distinct with random column MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've table `books` that contains image, language, faith. I'am getting distinct values for faith with

```
SELECT DISTINCT faith, language from books;
```

That fetches faith series (*15 results*) but I want to fetch `image` along too but randomly. So the result can be able to show faith with random image. How I can do that, please suggest.

Comment: This will involve two queries, or one especially ugly query.

Comment: You get distinct values for faith AND language with that query.

Comment: two `SELECTS` or Queries? could you please mention a sample.

Comment: So this query selects distinct faith-language combinations found in the table. And per result row you want an image. Just any of the whole table? Or any matching the faith? Or any matching the language? Or any matching both faith and language?

Comment: And "randomly" means everytime you run the query, it should be different images picked? Or does it mean you just don't care which, and you'd be fine with the query picking the same images every time?

Comment: @RanaHaroon can you provide a sample data like how your table look like, what you have tried and what are expecting from the data..kindly explain with example

Comment: @ThorstenKettner right, every time when query executed `faith` distinct list would be same each time but image should be randomly picked under the selected faith. `language` in distinct is not compulsory if it makes query complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to everybody, i got the solution from

> [Select random row per distinct field value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624968/select-random-row-per-distinct-field-value)

```
SELECT r.faith, 
(SELECT r1.image FROM books AS r1 WHERE r.faith=r1.faith ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) AS image FROM books AS r GROUP BY r.faith;
```

it's fetching distinct *field1* `faith` with random *field2* image against each faith everytime query executed.

Answer (score 2):

The query

```
select distinct faith, language from books;
```

selects distinct Faith-Language combinations from your table. So where your table contains two entries for the same Faith and Language

```
Faith  Language  Image
1      EN        img1
1      EN        img2
1      FR        img3
1      FR        img4
```

your result would contain each combination just once:

```
Faith  Language
1      EN
1      FR
```

It is not clear from your question yet, what you mean with a random image. Here is how you get one of the matching images for a Faith-Language combination arbitrarily picked:

```
select faith, language, image
from books
group by faith, language;
```

The result could look like this:

```
Faith  Language  Image
1      EN        img2
1      FR        img3
```

The reason is that we aggregate the rows. In the GROUP BY clause we say we want one result row per Faith and Language, but we also select Image and don't specify which one we'd like to see per group (which we could do with an aggregate function like MIN or MAX), so we just get one of the images matching the Faith-Language combination arbitrarily picked by the DBMS.

Is this already what you want?

Comment: i appreciate your input but this couldn't work please let me explain little more to understand. i have many rows in table `books` with different `faith` column. there's many BOOKS that are specified with faiths with it's own BOOK IMAGE. now i am fetching all the faiths from books table and i want to set a random image for the faith that can have 100 books against itself. each time when query is executed faith will remain same but image should be changed randomly each time
for instance 
--(faith: religious | image=modesty.jpg) 
--(faith: religious | image=book_of_religions.jpg)
leave language.